# How to perform the following change of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $f(t,x,y)$ such that $$f_t = \nabla^26f(t,x,y).$$ I want to perform a change of variables so that for $f(t',x',y')$ we have $$f_{t'} = \nabla^2f(t',x',y').$$ 
Expanding the original expression we get
$$f_t =  6\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)$$ and I know that $x$ is related to $x'$ by 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}.$$ Also, $y$ is related to $y'$ by a similar relation as above. I am trying to figure out where to go from here. I tried taking the derivative of the expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ but without any success. I am just looking for a hint on where to go next, not a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $(x',y',t') = (\alpha x,\alpha y,\alpha t)$ for some fixed number $\alpha$, to be determined.

Comment: I understand the way of getting rid of the $6$ by perhaps setting $\alpha = 1/6$ but I am still confused about how to take the derivative of $\alpha\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: $\frac\partial{\partial x} (\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}) = \alpha \frac\partial{\partial x'} (\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'})$.

Comment: Got it. Just one last question, how did you come up with that transformation? Just an educated guess? Or something else?

Comment: Experience with this sort of thing.